# What about installing an Antivirus on Windows K8s nodes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows

We're building an on-premise Kubernetes cluster with Windows nodes. As a company policy, all Windows Servers needs an antivirus (symantec endpoint security).

The antivirus would be installed on the nodes, and not as a pod.

What do you think about installing an antivirus on Kubernetes nodes? Considering the great chance of false-positives when an antivirus has to deal with Docker.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have much experience with Symantec (I don't really like the product).
But searching on Google apparently has some steps to set up, as they don't natively support Kuberentes as an application.

Look if these two articles can help you.

https://support.symantec.com/us/en/article.tech246815.html

https://www.symantec.com/content/dam/symantec/docs/solution-briefs/securing-containers-think-your-containers-are-secure-en.pdf